# GATT services using bluez aren`t be added?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, gatt

My problem :
I try to run the gatt-example server on the bluez 
I make:

1- sudo hciconfig hci0 leadv

2- sudo ./bluetoothd -d -n

3- I connect with a master and try to discover all primary services but every time I find 2 GAP services only why ??

I hope to find a person who can help me to run any profile and find all the services and attributes from the central device.

Answer (score 2):

You need to recompile bluez with `--enable-experimental` options and the run it with -E flag.

I have a small description here: https://github.com/jomarmar/bluez-experimental
which maybe of help.(Just for your info, I use Archlinux)